# How can I populate a Django ChoiceField with attributes of an object?

Tags: python, django

I have a `Election` and `Candidate` object model like so:

```
class Election(models.Model):
id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
region = models.CharField(max_length=80)
candidates_count = models.IntegerField()
total_votes_cast = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name


class Candidate(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    party = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    election_id = models.IntegerField()
    vote_count = models.IntegerField()

def __str__(self):
    return self.name
```

I have a form to create a new candidate, like so:

```
class AddNewCandidateForm(forms.Form):
PARTY_CHOICES = [
    (1, "Party 1"),
    (2, "Party 2"),
    (3, "Party 3"),
    (4, "Party 4"),
    (5, "Party 5"),
    (6, "Other")
]

candidate_name = forms.CharField(
    max_length=80,
    required=True,
    label='Candidate Name'
)

candidate_party = forms.ChoiceField(
    label='This candidates party',
    required=True,
    widget=forms.Select(),
    choices=PARTY_CHOICES
)

candidate_election = forms.ChoiceField(
    label="The election that this candidate is participating in",
    required=True,
    widget=forms.Select()
)
```

I want to populate the `candidate_election` `ChoiceField` with the `name` attribute of all of existing `Election` objects in the database.

What is the best way to do this? I'm struggling with ways to figure out how to make a 2-tuple for the `ChoiceField` to accept.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update your candidate_election variable to this

```
candidate_election = forms.ChoiceField(
    label="The election that this candidate is participating in",
    required=True,
    widget=forms.Select()
    choices=[(e.id,e.name) for e in Election.objects.all()]
)
```

Comment: How obvious... thanks!